# Como acessar dados retornados dentro de um objeto?

Tags: php, objetos

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de boletos e começando com orientação a objetos Preciso extrair os dados da seguinte estrutura dentro do meu abjeto, que foi alimentada pelo retorno do banco:

object(stdClass)[5]

public 'numero' => string '00031285570001357868' (length=20)

public 'numeroCarteira' => int 17

public 'numeroVariacaoCarteira' => int 35

public 'codigoCliente' => int 704950857

public 'linhaDigitavel' => string '00190000090312855700001357868171188810000500000' (length=47)

public 'codigoBarraNumerico' => string '00191888100005000000000003128557000135786817' (length=44)

public 'numeroContratoCobranca' => int 19581316

public 'beneficiario' =>

```
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'agencia' => int 452
  public 'contaCorrente' => int 123873
  public 'tipoEndereco' => int 9
  public 'logradouro' => string 'M SANTO ANTONIO DO DESCOBERTO AV GOIAS QUADRA 09 LOTES 4 E 6' (length=60)
  public 'bairro' => string 'SETOR DE INDUSTRIAS' (length=19)
  public 'cidade' => string 'SANTO ANTONIO DO DESCOBERTO' (length=27)
  public 'codigoCidade' => int 82496
  public 'uf' => string 'GO' (length=2)
  public 'cep' => int 72900000
  public 'indicadorComprovacao' => string '0' (length=1)
```

public 'qrCode' =>
object(stdClass)[7]
public 'url' => string '' (length=0)
public 'txId' => string '' (length=0)
public 'emv' => string '' (length=0)

Como faço isso???

Comment: Você pretende acessar os valores?

Comment: Sim, preciso desses valores para gerar o boleto e guardar em banco.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Uma vez que você tem esse objeto com os valores você pode acessar assim: `seuObjeto['agencia]`

Comment: Você pode usar assim $seuObjeto->agencia

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver convertendo a variável `$registro_info` que recebe o $data do objeto:

```
$registo_convertido = (get_object_vars($registro_info));
```

A partir do momento que converti os dados, passo a tratar a variável como um array comum.